# SFML program crashes with non-ASCII character in window title

Tags: c++, sfml

So i just install SFML and was trying to do a simple programme, and the compilation works fine, but it's when I try to run the executable that it fails.
First I needed to do a trick to authorize the application to launch because it wasn't recognize by apple I follow those instruction to install SFML https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php
After I managed to authorize the application when I run it I got this error message:

```
2020-11-24 10:20:55.638 exemple-graphisme1[2768:29657] *** Assertion failure in -[SFWindow setTitle:], NSWindow.m:2490
2020-11-24 10:20:55.640 exemple-graphisme1[2768:29657] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204956af __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201cd3c9 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204be512 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff212776c9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff22c7da75 -[NSWindow setTitle:] + 142
    5   libsfml-window.2.5.dylib            0x000000010e5bf4fd _ZN2sf4priv15WindowImplCocoaC2ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEmRKNS_15ContextSettingsE + 269
    6   libsfml-window.2.5.dylib            0x000000010e5b0e03 _ZN2sf4priv10WindowImpl6createENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE + 67
    7   libsfml-window.2.5.dylib            0x000000010e5b02e5 _ZN2sf6Window6createENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE + 469
    8   libsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib          0x000000010e61e823 _ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE + 99
    9   exemple-graphisme1                  0x000000010e582849 main + 233
    10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2033e631 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[1]    2768 abort      ./exemple-graphisme1
```

My code is very simple and only draw a point on the window

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
using Point = Vector2f;

void draw_point(RenderWindow& w, Point pos, Color color) {
    Vertex p[] = { Vertex(pos, color) };
    w.draw(p, 1, sf::Points);
}

int main()
{
    // ed: The line below originally contained "Hello World"
    RenderWindow    window(VideoMode(640, 480), "Ma super fenêtre");
    window.clear(Color::White);
    draw_point(window, {120, 5}, Color::Red);
    window.display();
    sleep(seconds(10));
    return 0;
}
```

And I compiled my programme like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 exemple-graphisme1.cpp -o exemple-graphisme1 -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Please build with debugging information enabled (add the `-g` flag when building) and you might be able to get a position in your source where it happens. If not then use a debugger to catch the assertion and go up the call stack to your code to see where it happens.

Comment: when i use lldb it crash as soon as I write process launch, and I edited my code to only put the first line and it crash with the same error message !

Comment: Can you try compiling with clang++ instead of g++? I see that libsfml was compiled with clang and its `std::string` is different from that in Clang.

Comment: @Botje Unless explicitly installed, `g++` is an alias of `clang++`. To the OP: Please run the command `g++ -v` to see what compiler you're really using.

Comment: g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: @Amition Please [edit] your question to show the output (formatted as code).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't understand what you ask, the error output on my question is already formatted as code no ?

Comment: And when I try to compile and execute the example given by the documentation of SFML and  it works perfectly fine !

Comment: The output of the `g++ -v` command. Notice how hard it is to read in a comment? It is also crucial information that should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was very simple, I edited my code to translate it in english but in the beginning the first line was

```
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "Ma super fenêtre");
```

And the error occured because of the character 'ê'.

Thanks for your answer and sorry for this disappointing answer !

Comment: This is the reason it's so important for questions to include a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to use non-ASCII characters you must use `sf::String::fromUtf8("Ma super fenêtre")`